# Prove by giving an example that completeness is significant in Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to give an example of space and family of operators to prove that completeness of space $X$ in Banach-Steinhaus (the uniform boundedness principle) is in fact needed.

I guess space $c_{00}$ would be one of proper places to look for the needed operators, but it's my intuition.

Comment: A good intuition. Look for a sequence such that $T_n(x) = 0$ for all large enough $n$, for every $x\in c_{00}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $c_{00}$ (the space of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms) is the prime candidate for counterexamples involving lack of completeness. The family of linear functionals $f_n(x) = nx_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, provides such a counterexample: bounded pointwise but not bounded in the norm.